# PHP Slim Framework Create Controller

Tags: php, controller, slim, slim-3

I am creating an API using the Slim framework.  Currently I use a single file to create the route and pass a closure to it:

```
$app->get('/', function($req, $resp){
//Code...
})
```

But I realise that my file has grown rapidly.  What I want to do is use controllers instead, so I will have a controller class and just pass the instance/static methods to the route, like below

```
class HomeController
{
   public static function index($req, $resp){}
}
```

and then pass the function to the route

```
$app->get('/', HomeController::index);
```

I tried this, but it does not work, and I wonder if there is a way I can use it to manage my files.

Answer (score 11):

Turn the controller into a functor:

```
class HomeController
{
    public function __invoke($req, $resp) {}
}
```

and then route like this:

```
$app->get('/', HomeController::class);
```

For reference, see

- http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#how-to-create-routes
- http://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#route-callbacks.

Comment: Which folder is used for add controller ?

Answer (score 3):

PHP 5.6
Slim 2.6.2

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

class HelloController {
    public static function index()  {
        global $app;

        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($app->request);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}

$app = new \Slim\Slim();
$app->get('/', 'HelloController::index');
$app->run();
```

**Update:** PHP 5.6 Slim 3.0.0

```
require 'vendor/autoload.php';

class HelloController {
    public static function hello(\Slim\Http\Request $req, \Slim\Http\Response $response, $args)  {
        echo "<pre>";
        var_dump($args);
        echo "</pre>";
    }
}

$app = new \Slim\App();
$app->get('/hello/{name}', 'HelloController::hello');
$app->run();
```

The problem with class based routing in Slim 3.0 is access to `$this`/`$app`. I think you will need to use `global $app` to access it.

In my pet project I use route groups with `require_once`. Something like

```
$app->group('/dashboard', function () {
    $this->group('/auctions', function () use ($app){
        require_once('routes/dashboard/auctions.php');
    });
    $this->group('/rss', function () {
        require_once('routes/dashboard/rss.php');
    });
    $this->group('/settings', function () {
        require_once('routes/dashboard/settings.php');
    });
});
```

Looks not as beauty as could be with pure classes but works like expected with all features accessible without additional coding.

Comment: If you subclass slim\application and include the route file inside there then you can use $this consistently throughout the route configuration. I added an example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981048/how-can-i-create-middleware-on-slim-framework-3/42022544#42022544

Also, it would be possible to have a route configuration class that takes the Application as a constructor dependency

Comment: @Roman when you use proper namespace and using composer, you do not need to call require() on your own because autoload.php will do it for you.

Answer (score 2):

Smooth & short way to use a controller as an object (not a static way)

> in index.php

```
namespace MyApp;

use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

require __DIR__ . '/../vendor/autoload.php';

$app->get('/myroute', [new Controller\MyClass, 'get']); // <=== that is pretty short  and neat
$app->post('/myroute', [new Controller\MyClass, 'post']);
$app->map(['GET', 'POST'], '/myotherrout', [new Controller\MyOtherClass, 'run']);
```

> in Controller/MyClass :

```
namespace MyApp\Controller;

class MyClass{

    public function __construct(){
       //some code
    }

    public function get(\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response, $args = []) {
       //some super foobar code
    }

    public function post(\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response, $args = []) {
       //some other code
    }
```

**The Controller\MyClass is resolved through the use of PSR autoload**

> in Controller/MyOtherClass :

```
namespace MyApp\Controller;

class MyOtherClass{

    public function __construct(){
       //some code
    }

    public function run(\Slim\Http\Request $request, \Slim\Http\Response $response, $args = []) {
       //some amazing foobar code
    }
```

Comment: Very nice indeed! Thanks! How would you inject a service directly into the controller without going through the container using this?

Comment: While this works, controller instance creation should be done inside dependency container registration

Answer (score 2):

Here's an example:

## Controller

```
<?php

use Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface;
use Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface;
use Psr\Log\LoggerInterface;

/**
 * @property LoggerInterface $logger;
 */
class Controller
{
    /**
     * @var LoggerInterface
     */
    protected $logger

    /**
     * @param LoggerInterface $logger
     */
    public function __construct($logger)
    {
        $this->logger = $logger;
    }

    public function action(ServerRequestInterface $request, ResponseInterface $response, $args=[])
    {
        $this->logger->info((string)$request->getUri());
        /* some actions */
        return $response;
    }
}
```

## Application

```
<?php

use Slim\App;
use Slim\Container;
use Psr\Container\ContainerInterface;

$autoloader = require(__DIR__.'/vendor/autoload.php');

$container = new Container();

$container['logger'] = function($container) {
    return new Logger();
}

$container['some.controller'] = function ($container) {
    /**
     * @var ContainerInterface $container
     */
    $logger = $container->get('logger');

    return new Controller($logger);
};

$app = new App($container);
$app->get('/some/route', 'some.controller:action');

$app->run();
```

## Profit!

This method is described in the documentation [click me](https://www.slimframework.com/docs/v3/objects/router.html#container-resolution)

Comment: I see you pass $logger to the controller, should you not pass the container?

Comment: @crafter passing a container to a controller is a bad practice. see https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Single_responsibility_principle and https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dependency_injection

Comment: I hear you. You are correct, that container is too large to drag along into your classes.

Answer (score 1):

Nikic's Fast Route is a very minimal router, so some of the niceties of the bigger frameworks are removed. Here's a basic solution:

routes.php

```
use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

$app->get('/', function($req, $resp, $args) use ($app){return FooBar::asdf($app, $req, $resp);});
```

controller
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ServerRequestInterface as Request;
    use \Psr\Http\Message\ResponseInterface as Response;

```
class FooBar{
    static public function asdf(Slim\App $app, Request $req, Response $resp, $args = [])
    {
        return $resp->withJson(['asf']);
    }
}
```