# PHP Slim 3 Framework - where can I put my controller file?

Tags: php, frameworks, slim-3

I registering a controller with the container, but it seems not working because it doesn't match to the correct location.

\slim\src\routes.php

```
<?php
// Routes
$app->get('/dd', 'App\controllers\HomeController:home');
```

\slim\App\controllers\HomeController.php

```
<?php
class HomeController 
{
   protected $container;

   // constructor receives container instance
   public function __construct(ContainerInterface $container) {
       $this->container = $container;
   }

   public function home($request, $response, $args) {
        // your code
        // to access items in the container... $this->container->get('');
        return $response;
   }

   public function contact($request, $response, $args) {
        // your code
        // to access items in the container... $this->container->get('');
        return $response;
   }
}
```

My project folder structure:

```
\slim
　　\public
　　　　index.php
　　　　.htaccess

　　\App
　　　　\controllers
　　　　　　HomeController.php

　　\src
　　　　dependencies.php
　　　　middleware.php
　　　　routes.php
　　　　settings.php

　　\templates
　　　　index.phtml

　　\vendor
　　　　\slim
```

Maybe I should to setting **\slim\src\settings.php**?

Because it show Slim Application Error:

> Type: RuntimeException Message: Callable
>   App\controllers\HomeController does not exist File:
>   D:\htdocs\slim\vendor\slim\slim\Slim\CallableResolver.php Line: 90

Last, I also refer to these articles:
https://www.slimframework.com/docs/objects/router.html#container-resolution

PHP Slim Framework Create Controller
[PHP Slim Framework Create Controller](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34539021/php-slim-framework-create-controller)

How can i create middleware on Slim Framework 3?
[How can i create middleware on Slim Framework 3?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41981048/how-can-i-create-middleware-on-slim-framework-3/42022544#42022544)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add psr-4 to your composer file so that you're able to call your namespaces.

```
{
    "require": {
        "slim/slim": "^3.12
    },
    "autoload": {
        "psr-4": {
            "App\\": "app"
        }
    }
}
```

This PSR describes a specification for autoloading classes from file paths. Then in your routes.php file add this at the top :

```
<?php
    use app\controllers\HomeController;
    // Routes
    $app->get('/dd', 'App\controllers\HomeController:home');
```

and finally in your HomeController.php file add :

```
<?php
    namespace app\controllers;
    class HomeController 
    {
    //.. your code
    }
```

hope this helps...:)